# How to get hierarchical tree structure from JSON API endpoint data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My JSON endpoint API output data from database in JSON format. Here are the structure of my output data while calling api

```
print_r($allItems->data);

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 1 [mma_nam] => Data Entry [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => iDEntry ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 2 [mma_nam] => Reports [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => iReports ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 3 [mma_nam] => Utilities [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => iUtils ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 4 [mma_nam] => Extras [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => iExit ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 5 [mma_nam] => Order [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iEstmAdd ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 6 [mma_nam] => Vouchres [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => VchMast ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 7 [mma_nam] => Billing [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iWBill ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 8 [mma_nam] => Production [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => ProdMstr ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 9 [mma_nam] => Purchase [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => PurMstr ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 10 [mma_nam] => Issues [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => issubrow ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 11 [mma_nam] => Post dated voucher [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => PendVchr ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 12 [mma_nam] => Damage\other issue [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iDamAdd ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 13 [mma_nam] => Forms [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aFtrMenu ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 14 [mma_nam] => Debit/Credit Note [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => DcMaster ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 15 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aFixMenu ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 16 [mma_nam] => Machinery [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => MachFl ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 17 [mma_nam] => Leave etc. [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => LvMaster ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 18 [mma_nam] => Ingrediants [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aIngrMen ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 19 [mma_nam] => Barcode Sales order [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => BCodeOrd ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 20 [mma_nam] => Hrd [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => HrdProg ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 21 [mma_nam] => Transfer stock [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aTraMenu ) [21] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 22 [mma_nam] => Dealer Details [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => DealeDet ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 23 [mma_nam] => Specification [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aSpecMenu ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 24 [mma_nam] => Bay Master [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aBayMenu ) [24] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 25 [mma_nam] => Master Barcode [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aMastBar ) [25] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 26 [mma_nam] => Purchase Order menu [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => PrchOrd ) [26] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 27 [mma_nam] => Job Card [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aJobMenu ) [27] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 28 [mma_nam] => Passbook [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aSpMenu ) [28] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 29 [mma_nam] => Incentives [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => incut ) [29] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 30 [mma_nam] => Spare Request [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => SpareHis ) [30] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 31 [mma_nam] => Conversion Menu [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aConvMenu ) [31] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 32 [mma_nam] => Shop Invoice- 1 [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iShopInv ) [32] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 33 [mma_nam] => Barcode Invoice [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iBBill ) [33] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 34 [mma_nam] => Substore Sales Order [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iEstmAdd ) [34] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 35 [mma_nam] => Substore billing [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => SubStOne ) [35] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 36 [mma_nam] => Issue barcoded Items [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aBarMenu ) [36] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 37 [mma_nam] => Miscellaneous Issue [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iMiscIsu ) [37] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 38 [mma_nam] => Subst. Return to Main. Store [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iRt2Main ) [38] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 39 [mma_nam] => Complaint Register [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => CmpltReg ) [39] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 40 [mma_nam] => Case Diary [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => CaseDia ) [40] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 41 [mma_nam] => Receipt [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => iEVchRec ) [41] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 42 [mma_nam] => Entries to upload [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => aUpload ) [42] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 43 [mma_nam] => Company Calender [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => CmpCal ) [43] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 44 [mma_nam] => Freezer System [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => frezrdet ) [44] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 45 [mma_nam] => Board order details [mma_pid] => 1 [mma_url] => BoardDet ) [45] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 46 [mma_nam] => Sales Register [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iSaleReg ) [46] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 47 [mma_nam] => Excise Reports [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aExcMen ) [47] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 48 [mma_nam] => Stock Stmnt [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iStockSt ) [48] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 49 [mma_nam] => Cash/Bank Book [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iCashBk ) [49] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 50 [mma_nam] => Trial Balance [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iTrialBl ) [50] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 51 [mma_nam] => Sub A/c Stmnt [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iSubst ) [51] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 52 [mma_nam] => Accts Ledger [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iALedger ) [52] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 53 [mma_nam] => Journal Book [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iJournal ) [53] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 54 [mma_nam] => Stock Ledger [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iSLedger ) [54] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 55 [mma_nam] => Sales Report [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iSaleRep ) [55] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 56 [mma_nam] => Data Checking [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => DataChk ) [56] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 57 [mma_nam] => Shop Reports [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aShopMen ) [57] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 58 [mma_nam] => Profit and Loss A/c [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iProfLos ) [58] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 59 [mma_nam] => Wastage analysis [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => WastNew ) [59] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 60 [mma_nam] => Log Sheet [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aLogMen ) [60] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 61 [mma_nam] => Increment Reports [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aIncMen ) [61] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 62 [mma_nam] => Special Reports [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aSplMen ) [62] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 63 [mma_nam] => Stock and Inventory [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aStkMen ) [63] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 64 [mma_nam] => Location wise stock [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iChkStor ) [64] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 65 [mma_nam] => Freezer Details [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aFrezMen ) [65] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 66 [mma_nam] => Purchase Register [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iPrchReg ) [66] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 67 [mma_nam] => Hrd Menu [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aHrdMen ) [67] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 68 [mma_nam] => VAT Reports [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aVatRep ) [68] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 69 [mma_nam] => Manufacturing Account [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iManAct ) [69] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 70 [mma_nam] => Consolidated Acts Ledger [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iConsAct ) [70] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 71 [mma_nam] => Special Discount Report [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iDiscSum ) [71] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 72 [mma_nam] => Machine wise Prod. Report [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aMacMen ) [72] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 73 [mma_nam] => Part stock check report [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => iStkPart ) [73] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 74 [mma_nam] => MIS Reports [mma_pid] => 2 [mma_url] => aMisMen ) [74] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 75 [mma_nam] => Remove Index Files [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => Delfilin ) [75] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 76 [mma_nam] => Backup Data [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => fBackup ) [76] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 77 [mma_nam] => Load Manuals [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iSeleMnl ) [77] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 78 [mma_nam] => Upd. Opening Bal [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aOBalMen ) [78] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 79 [mma_nam] => Status Report [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iStatRep ) [79] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 80 [mma_nam] => Delete Bre [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iRemBre ) [80] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 81 [mma_nam] => Send to Exchange [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iSLo2Ex ) [81] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 82 [mma_nam] => Send to File [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iSLo2Dsk ) [82] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 83 [mma_nam] => Send via Exchange [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iSViaEx ) [83] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 84 [mma_nam] => Receive from Exchange [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iREx2Lo ) [84] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 85 [mma_nam] => Receive from File [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iRDsk2Lo ) [85] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 86 [mma_nam] => Receive via Exchange [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iRViaEx ) [86] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 87 [mma_nam] => Pack Files [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iSelPack ) [87] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 88 [mma_nam] => Change Account transaction [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iChgNCod ) [88] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 89 [mma_nam] => Change Inventory transaction [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iChgICod ) [89] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 90 [mma_nam] => EDP Test (Salim) [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aSalim ) [90] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 91 [mma_nam] => EDP Test (Gopi) [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aTEdpMen ) [91] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 92 [mma_nam] => General [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aGeneral ) [92] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 93 [mma_nam] => Miscellaneous transfer [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => MisTrans ) [93] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 94 [mma_nam] => EDP Test (Sreemol) [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aSreemol ) [94] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 95 [mma_nam] => EDP Test (Silu) [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aSilu ) [95] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 96 [mma_nam] => Current User List [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iUseList ) [96] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 97 [mma_nam] => Sales Tax forms [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => sTaxBrow ) [97] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 98 [mma_nam] => Barcode Print [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aBarCMen ) [98] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 99 [mma_nam] => Punching Details [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aPunchMen ) [99] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 100 [mma_nam] => Salary Slip\Leave report [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aSalary ) [100] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 101 [mma_nam] => Replace Misc. Item Name [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => ReplName ) [101] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 102 [mma_nam] => Change Quantity Discount [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iChgqdi ) [102] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 103 [mma_nam] => List of Carriage Outward [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iCoutRep ) [103] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 104 [mma_nam] => Substore [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => Substbrw ) [104] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 105 [mma_nam] => Error List [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iErrView ) [105] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 106 [mma_nam] => Advance [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => aAdvMen ) [106] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 107 [mma_nam] => Send - Receive Status [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iStaSeRe ) [107] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 108 [mma_nam] => Overtime Statement [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iOtSlip ) [108] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 109 [mma_nam] => Un cleared check status [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iChkPass ) [109] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 110 [mma_nam] => Set/Reset Right [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iStRight ) [110] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 111 [mma_nam] => View clear Bank balance [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iActBal ) [111] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 112 [mma_nam] => Price History (All Items) [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iPriHist ) [112] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 113 [mma_nam] => View Single Item Price/Mrp [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => iVPriMrp ) [113] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 114 [mma_nam] => Browse Files [mma_pid] => 133 [mma_url] => iFMs ) [114] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 115 [mma_nam] => Change Password [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => iChgPass ) [115] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 116 [mma_nam] => Version Number [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => iProgDet ) [116] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 117 [mma_nam] => SMS Program [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => SmsProgm ) [117] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 118 [mma_nam] => Email Program [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => iEmail ) [118] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 119 [mma_nam] => Remainder [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => aCalMen ) [119] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 120 [mma_nam] => Print text file [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => PrnText ) [120] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 121 [mma_nam] => Account Head File [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aActMenu ) [121] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 122 [mma_nam] => Change Level [mma_pid] => 4 [mma_url] => sChgLevel ) [122] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 123 [mma_nam] => Add a New File [mma_pid] => 133 [mma_url] => iFlCreat ) [123] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 124 [mma_nam] => Delete a File [mma_pid] => 133 [mma_url] => iFlDel ) [124] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 125 [mma_nam] => Modify File Details [mma_pid] => 133 [mma_url] => iFlModi ) [125] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 126 [mma_nam] => View File Details [mma_pid] => 133 [mma_url] => iViewStr ) [126] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 127 [mma_nam] => Customer File [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aCustMenu ) [127] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 128 [mma_nam] => Inventory File [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aInvMenu ) [128] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 129 [mma_nam] => Variable Dictionary [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iMastMod ) [129] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 130 [mma_nam] => User File [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aUsrMenu ) [130] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 131 [mma_nam] => Field Dictionary [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iMastMod ) [131] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 132 [mma_nam] => Master Maintenance [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => iMNmaint ) [132] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 133 [mma_nam] => File Maintenance [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => iFMaint ) [133] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 134 [mma_nam] => Log Off [mma_pid] => 0 [mma_url] => LogOf ) [134] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 135 [mma_nam] => Accounts Grand Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aAgmMenu ) [135] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 136 [mma_nam] => Inventory Grand Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aIgmMenu ) [136] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 137 [mma_nam] => Form Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aForMenu ) [137] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 138 [mma_nam] => Special Price File [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aSplMenu ) [138] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 139 [mma_nam] => Barcode Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => PutBarCo ) [139] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 140 [mma_nam] => Mail List Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iMliAdd ) [140] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 141 [mma_nam] => Cheque Leaf no entry [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iChkLfNo ) [141] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 142 [mma_nam] => Voucher Reverse [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iVchRev ) [142] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 143 [mma_nam] => Item Production\Issue [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => MixPro ) [143] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 144 [mma_nam] => Price Ratio\MRP file [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aChgRatio ) [144] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 145 [mma_nam] => Phone Book [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iTelDir ) [145] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 146 [mma_nam] => Message File [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iMastMod ) [146] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 147 [mma_nam] => Upd.Email Id\Mobile No [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iPhemail ) [147] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 148 [mma_nam] => Item Specification [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => spcbrw ) [148] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 149 [mma_nam] => Item general Packing [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => UpdtPac ) [149] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 150 [mma_nam] => Purchase forecast gen. [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => fcst ) [150] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 151 [mma_nam] => Change Inventory Price [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aInvPMenu ) [151] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 152 [mma_nam] => Log Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aLMaMenu ) [152] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 153 [mma_nam] => Log Detail [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => logdetls ) [153] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 154 [mma_nam] => Freight Rate file [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => Frt_Rate ) [154] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 155 [mma_nam] => Pancard Master file [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => Pancard ) [155] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 156 [mma_nam] => Add Screen Help [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iHelpAdd ) [156] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 157 [mma_nam] => Intercash Deletion [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => iIntCash ) [157] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 158 [mma_nam] => Agreement types [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => agtadd ) [158] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 159 [mma_nam] => Shift Master [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aShmMenu ) [159] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 160 [mma_nam] => Shift allotment [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => shdallot ) [160] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 161 [mma_nam] => Contact file [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aContact ) [161] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 162 [mma_nam] => Menu\URL addition [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => MenMast ) [162] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 163 [mma_nam] => Update Price file [mma_pid] => 132 [mma_url] => aChgPMenu ) [163] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 164 [mma_nam] => Add Bay master code [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => iBayAdd ) [164] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 165 [mma_nam] => Delete Bay master code [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => iBayDel ) [165] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 166 [mma_nam] => Modify Bay master code [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => iBayMod ) [166] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 167 [mma_nam] => Add\Print bay barcode [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => BayBarco ) [167] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 168 [mma_nam] => Add Items to bay location [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => itmStloc ) [168] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 169 [mma_nam] => Bay Checking routine [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => BastChk ) [169] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 170 [mma_nam] => Location wise List [mma_pid] => 24 [mma_url] => LocDet ) [170] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 171 [mma_nam] => Create Master Barcode [mma_pid] => 25 [mma_url] => CrtMasBc ) [171] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 172 [mma_nam] => Split Master Barcode [mma_pid] => 25 [mma_url] => SpltMast ) [172] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 173 [mma_nam] => View Master Barcode [mma_pid] => 25 [mma_url] => VMastBco ) [173] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 174 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Addition [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFasAdd ) [174] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 175 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Deletion [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFasDel ) [175] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 176 [mma_nam] => Print Fixed Asset Voucher [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFasPrn ) [176] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 177 [mma_nam] => Sale Fixed Asset [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaSale ) [177] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 178 [mma_nam] => Split Fixed Asset [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaSplit ) [178] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 179 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Stock Transfer [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaTrans ) [179] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 180 [mma_nam] => Write off Fixed Asset [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaWof ) [180] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 181 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Register [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFasRep ) [181] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 182 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Schedule [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaSched ) [182] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 183 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Adjustments [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iAlterFa ) [183] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 184 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Return to supplier [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaRetn ) [184] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 185 [mma_nam] => Remove Fixed Asset Adjustment [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => FaltDel ) [185] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 186 [mma_nam] => List Fixed Asset Date wise [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaDet ) [186] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 187 [mma_nam] => List Asset with bill details [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaSupDt ) [187] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 188 [mma_nam] => Sale of fixed asset date wise [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iListSal ) [188] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 189 [mma_nam] => List Returned Asset Date wise [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iListRet ) [189] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 190 [mma_nam] => List Stock Transferred Asset [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iListTrf ) [190] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 191 [mma_nam] => List Placement number wise [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFasPnu ) [191] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 192 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Alteration Report [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => FaChgRep ) [192] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 193 [mma_nam] => List Of Written Off Assets [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => FastLst ) [193] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 194 [mma_nam] => List of retained earning [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaReter ) [194] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 195 [mma_nam] => Fixed Asset Old Entry Addn [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => aOldFa ) [195] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 196 [mma_nam] => Asset Allotment [mma_pid] => 15 [mma_url] => iFaAdFld ) [196] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 197 [mma_nam] => Menu List [mma_pid] => 3 [mma_url] => menu_list ) [197] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 198 [mma_nam] => Customer List [mma_pid] => 7 [mma_url] => customer_list ) [198] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 199 [mma_nam] => igm add [mma_pid] => 136 [mma_url] => igm_add ) [199] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 200 [mma_nam] => test1 [mma_pid] => 7 [mma_url] => test1 ) [200] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 201 [mma_nam] => Cutomer Add [mma_pid] => 135 [mma_url] => customer_add ) [201] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 202 [mma_nam] => Add Normal Account a/c [mma_pid] => 135 [mma_url] => add_normalac ) [202] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 203 [mma_nam] => Add Share Holder [mma_pid] => 135 [mma_url] => add_shareholder ) [203] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 204 [mma_nam] => Add M/C [mma_pid] => 16 [mma_url] => add_machinery ) [204] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 205 [mma_nam] => Add [mma_pid] => 20 [mma_url] => add_hrd ) [205] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 206 [mma_nam] => Add [mma_pid] => 23 [mma_url] => add_specifications ) [206] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 207 [mma_nam] => Add [mma_pid] => 39 [mma_url] => add_complaintreg ) [207] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 208 [mma_nam] => Add To Shift Master [mma_pid] => 159 [mma_url] => shift ) [208] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 209 [mma_nam] => update single item price [mma_pid] => 163 [mma_url] => pricesng ) [209] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 210 [mma_nam] => salim-test1 [mma_pid] => 90 [mma_url] => salim-test1 ) [210] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 211 [mma_nam] => Browse table [mma_pid] => 90 [mma_url] => tableview ) [211] => stdClass Object ( [mma_mid] => 212 [mma_nam] => NewUserTest [mma_pid] => 91 [mma_url] => newUserFrm ) )
```

That is my api returns four fields with value from database. mma_mid, mma_nam, mma_pid and mma_url. With this php code I get all the parent data from the above data

```
foreach ($allItems->data as $menu) {

        if($menu->mma_pid == 0){
            $test1 .= $menu->mma_mid." ".$menu->mma_nam."<br>";
            }
              
    }    
 
echo $test1."<br>";
```

and the output is as below

```
1 Data Entry
2 Reports
3 Utilities
4 Extras
132 Master Maintenance
133 File Maintenance
134 Log Off
```

My need is to print all child data under parent data with child-mma_pid equal to parent-mma_mid. How can I achieve this ? any help will be appreciated and helpful. Thanks in advance.

I tried a two if conditions but it gives no result

```
foreach ($allItems->data as $menu) {
        if($menu->mma_pid == 0){
            $test1 .= $menu->mma_mid." ".$menu->mma_nam."<br>";
            if($menu->mma_mid == $menu->mma_pid ){
                $test1 .= $menu->mma_mid." ".$menu->mma_nam."<br>";
            }
         }       
    }    
 
echo $test1;
```

Comment: Don't print out the tree immediately. Iterate over the items and create a second array that holds the structure you want with maybe a "children" key for each item, that holds the items' children. To output, iterate over that second array.

Comment: Could you help me with any code samples ? @brombeer

Comment: Could you try yourself first, please? You know how to foreach and it seems how to create an array

Comment: @brombeer why I ask here I am unable to get a solution myself . anyway thanks for the time and comments. I will try and and am trying for last few days to get it done.

Comment: You could/should post one of your tries along with errors you get or where it fails. The code you posted doesn't show any effort trying to output child elements. The superdirty and _not recommended_ way would be to iterate over the items a second time with a different condition. I gave you hints on how to do it in a cleaner way. Ideally, the JSON you get would already be structured the way you want it. Feel free to ask any question if you run into problems

Comment: well I tried this way "The superdirty and not recommended way would be to iterate over the items a second time with a different condition" I put a condition inside my if condition and it returns nothing !!

Comment: Then why didn't you post _that_ code? There's no use discussing/trying to fix code we don't see. Good luck

Comment: foreach ($allItems->data as $menu) {
        if($menu->mma_pid == 0){
            $test1 .= $menu->mma_mid." ".$menu->mma_nam."<br>";
            if($menu->mma_mid == $menu->mma_pid ){
                $test1 .= $menu->mma_mid." ".$menu->mma_nam."<br>";
            }
         }       
    }    
 
echo $test1; this was the code @brombeer

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a helper array to hold the references to each parent - as explained in https://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147134343/create-a-parent-child-array-structure-in-one-pass

```php
$refs = array();
$list = array();

$sql = "SELECT item_id, parent_id, name FROM items ORDER BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($data = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $thisref = &$refs[ $data['item_id'] ];

    $thisref['parent_id'] = $data['parent_id'];
    $thisref['name'] = $data['name'];

    if ($data['parent_id'] == 0) {
        $list[ $data['item_id'] ] = &$thisref;
    } else {
        $refs[ $data['parent_id'] ]['children'][ $data['item_id'] ] = &$thisref;
    }
}
```

Ignore the obsolete `mysql_` functions - they are not important for understanding the solution.